# В bootstrap 4 в сетке row>col не работает псевдокласс :hover

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap4

Я хотел чтобы каждая ячейка меняла поведение при наведении (меняла цвет, шрифт,прозрачность), но элементы не реагируют. За пределами таблицы (без использования bootstrap классов) все работает.
HTML:

```css
#content {
  font-family: Garamond;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 90px;
  top: -50px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: rgba(74, 0, 128, 0.8);
}

.item-icons {
  border: 2px solid white;
  line-height: 70px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-icons:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="content">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="content-row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <h1>Приветствуем вас на нашем сайте</h1>
        <p class="text">Мы занимаемся строительными работами: </p>
        <!-- В этой таблице не работает псевдокласс :hover -->
        <div class="container box-icons text-center">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col item-icons ">1</div>
            <div class="col item-icons">2</div>
            <div class="col item-icons">3</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col item-icons">4</div>
            <div class="col item-icons">5</div>
            <div class="col item-icons">6</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col item-icons">7</div>
            <div class="col item-icons">8</div>
            <div class="col item-icons">9</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Конец таблицы -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 justify-content-center"><img id="image" width="600" height="400" src="resource/img/csm_Handwerk_Slider_0f05da8a81.jpg" alt="Builder"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все у вас работает уберите `z-index: -1;` он просто невидит что мышь над ним

```css
#content {
  font-family: Garamond;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 90px;
  top: -50px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(74, 0, 128, 0.8);
}

.item-icons {
  border: 2px solid white;
  line-height: 70px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-icons:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="content">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="content-row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <h1>Приветствуем вас на нашем сайте</h1>
        <p class="text">Мы занимаемся строительными работами: </p>
        <!-- В этой таблице не работает псевдокласс :hover -->
        <div class="container box-icons text-center">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col item-icons ">1</div>
            <div class="col item-icons">2</div>
            <div class="col item-icons">3</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col item-icons">4</div>
            <div class="col item-icons">5</div>
            <div class="col item-icons">6</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col item-icons">7</div>
            <div class="col item-icons">8</div>
            <div class="col item-icons">9</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Конец таблицы -->
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```